# Dojox Calendar Widget shows only six days in a week

Tags: dojo, calendar

Running first demo on this page -

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/widget/Calendar.html#dojox-widget-calendar

shows only six days in a week (Saturday is missing). Any idea what to do to get all seven days in the week in this calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with the Claro Theme (the [other themes](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/widget/tests/test_Calendar.html?theme=tundra) are working fine).  I imagine that that particular widget hasn't been since the inclusion of the Claro Theme to dijit.  Have you looked at the dijit.Calendar widget?  Does that suit your needs?  If not there is also a new [heavyweight Calendar](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/calendar) Widget as a Candidate for dojo 1.8.

To demonstrate why I think this is am issue with the Claro theme:

css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/widget/Calendar/Calendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
```

js:

```
dojo.require("dojox.widget.Calendar");
dojo.require('dojo.parser');
dojo.ready(function() {
    dojo.parser.parse();
});
```

html:

```
​<body class="claro">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.widget.Calendar" id="cal"></div>
​</body>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Note that the calendar displays as you see on the demo page.  Now swap out `​<body class="claro">` with `​<body class="tundra">` and see how the Calendar is different.

Comment: Thanks... Never thought theme could be an issue.